# Adding custom markers to C++ source code that perf can find and Hotspot show

Tags: c++, linux, performance, profiling, perf

for a profiling scenario, I would like to ask if it is possible to emit signals from c++ source code that linux perf can detect and that Hotspot GUI can show and filter for. I have a scenario where some method sometimes takes very long and I want to see these points in the hotspot timeline.

Regards

Comment: You can use `perf probe`s on userspace code to manage the first part of your question. However I am not aware how to isolate that in Hotspot

Comment: I would increase probing frequency of perf to 199 or even more. Kill all processes that you can on the system. This kind of profilings are dependent on building flags.